# Use formula in LINQ selection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable that looks like this:

```
Row Side    Value
1   A       34.8
1   B       33.9
1   C       33.1
2   A       32.6
2   B       32.0
2   C       35.7
3   A       34.6
3   B       34.0
3   C       33.5
```

One thing I needed to do was compute the average of each Row which I did like:

```
var avg = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
          group row by new { RowMeas = row.Field<string>("Row") } into grp
          select new
          {
             RowMeas = grp.Key.RowMeas,
             AVG = grp.Average(r => r.Field<double>("Value"))
         }).ToList();
```

Now I need to do something similar but instead of just taking the average I want to use a formula for each row like `4*A + 3*B + 2*C`

Can I do this using LINQ like above but instead of AVG somehow work this formula in?  In other software we do this calculation manually by transposing the datatable so that there are A, B, C columns which can then be used in an formula on a new column.  Since there's not an easy way to transpose in C# I'm hoping I can do this using LINQ.

Comment: Entity Framework's LINQ query language is, AFAIK, constrained in what it can do to what T-SQL can do.  SQL Server has a pretty simple set of _Aggregate_ functions, and so EF can do things that invoke those functions.  What you really want to do is _Pivot_ the query, so that you get an A-Value, a B-Value and a C-Value for each `Row`.  If you could do that, doing your calculation (in C#) would be trivial.  Doing a simple search for LINQ, EF and the word "pivot" makes it look like you're mostly out of luck.  Someone else might chime in, but it doesn't look good.  I hope my comments help.

Comment: In doing further research it does seem that is the way to go, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100671/how-to-change-datatable-rows-to-columns-in-c-sharp  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Row", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Side", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(double));

dt.Rows.Add(1, "A", 34.8);
dt.Rows.Add(1, "B", 33.9);
dt.Rows.Add(1, "C", 33.1);
dt.Rows.Add(2, "A", 32.6);
dt.Rows.Add(2, "B", 32.0);
dt.Rows.Add(2, "C", 35.7);
dt.Rows.Add(3, "A", 34.6);
dt.Rows.Add(3, "B", 34.0);
dt.Rows.Add(3, "C", 33.5);

var query = dt
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Row"))
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Row = x.Key,
        A = x.Where(y => y.Field<string>("Side") == "A").Select(z => z.Field<double>("Value")).FirstOrDefault(),
        B = x.Where(y => y.Field<string>("Side") == "B").Select(z => z.Field<double>("Value")).FirstOrDefault(),
        C = x.Where(y => y.Field<string>("Side") == "C").Select(z => z.Field<double>("Value")).FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Row = x.Row,
        Result = 4 * x.A + 3 * x.B + 2 * x.C
    })
    ;

foreach (var q in query)
    Console.WriteLine("Row = {0}, Result = {1}", q.Row, q.Result);
```

Result in LinqPad.
[image]

Comment: Yeah, but that's not an EF query.  I somehow doubt that that will work if you were to use that query against a database.

Comment: OP never mentions EF. In fact they start off with "I have a DataTable" and use DataTable/DataRow methods

Comment: Thank you both.  Yes, I already had the datatable that I needed to manipulate so Han's answer worked out great.  I will keep Flydog's in mind for future use for EF queries.